# Rails grocer doesn't send push notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, apple-push-notifications

I have this code below:

```
    def build_push_notification
      pusher = Grocer.pusher(
        certificate: "..", # change path 
        gateway: "gateway.push.apple.com",
        port: 2195
      )

      notification = Grocer::Notification.new(
        device_token:      "..",
        alert:             "У вас новый заказ!",
        badge:             42
      )
      pusher.push(notification)
    end
```

In "certificate" and "device_token" i have i valid data. I'm just push a notification to iOS device and this was no errors.

**pusher.push(notification)** returns value and it seems be good. But there are no push notification in iOS device.

What i do wrong?

May i have troubles with certificate?

Comment: Try to change `gateway` to `gateway: 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com'` also is your certificate have a passphrase?

Comment: No, they haven't.  Ok, i will try it.

Comment: I have one thought about it. Mybe a should open a 2195 port?

Comment: I don't use the `port` option, it's optional.

Comment: I try to change gateway, but no result.